# wtforms datetimefield validation

Tags: flask, wtforms

I have below wtform field. I want to validate, day name (%A) with input DayMonYear(%d%b%Y)

```
stime = DateTimeField(label='Start time(UTC)', validators=[validators.InputRequired()], format="%A %d%b%Y %H:%M",
                          default=datetime.utcnow)
```

Sunday 15Sep2017 15:16
So, if anyone changes it to Friday 15Sep2017 15:16, should throw error. Do we have any such validators ?

Comment: There's no built in validator that does that. You can write a custom validator though. http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validators.html#custom-validators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, there is no defined wtforms vaildator for datetime.
As a workaround, used JavaScript getDay() to get actual Day for date mon year provided and compared it with value provided for day

```
Example:Friday 15Sep2017 19:39 :
    var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
     var d = new Date(giventime);
    s = giventime.split(/[ ,]+/)[0] # to get only "day"
    (s.toLowerCase() == days[d.getDay()].toLowerCase()) #condition
```